# debugging Flex event flow

Tags: apache-flex, debugging

I'm stepping through my code to figure out why a certain function takes more time to run the first time it gets called than on successive calls. The code flow for each function call is the same up to when a dispatchEvent gets called. I'm pretty sure it's different afterwards, as that call takes a lot more time the first time around. Unfortunately, I have no idea which other parts of the code chew on this specific event and thus cannot step through the handling of such event.

The question: is there a way to either figure out who handles such events or magically step through the handling code without explicitly setting breakpoints there?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in an easy fashion, no.  It's a pro and con of Flash (or any event based framework).  You don't know *when* it's fired, *where* it's fired from (think bubbling), or *who* is listening for it.  But at the same time, anyone could listen for any event, from anywhere (so long as it's within the display tree).

Normally what I do is just do a workspace search (ctrl+H in Flash Builder) and search for that specific event (you should be using static constants for dispatching/listening event types) and see who's doing what.